# SPLIT function in Google Sheets with csv, but ignore comma between quotation marks

Tags: google-sheets, split

I need to split this to columns, but ignore the comma between the quotation marks:

```
05-10-2022,14:43,"Unaforma LLS LS-,27285714",GD00B7KR2P84,FRA,FRAB,-715,3.3950,EUR,2427.43,EUR,2427.43,EUR,,-4.90,EUR,2422.53,EUR,b39cf45c-b5c8-4ee1-982f-0ad2fd704dde
```

I honestly have no idea how to do this. I tried using the split function, but then it also splits the comma between the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Can you test:*

```js
=arrayformula(substitute(split(regexreplace(A2,"""(.*?)(,)(.*?)""","$1$3"),","),"",","))
```

[image]

Comment: That seems to be doing it. Great, thanks a lot!! 

Now I have to figure out how this formula works :) And maybe a dumb question, but how the heck does that fish emoticon actually work inside a formula? :0 And what symbols does it represent?

Comment: the comma inside quotes is temp replaced with the fish symbol → then split is done → fish is again replaced by comma

Comment: Okay, but isn't the fish symbol a combination of characters? Like a smiley :-)

Comment: One more question if that's ok. I understand what the formula does, but how can you use the single cell formula 'substitute' after a split is done? Doesn't the split formula split the data over multiple cells?